# Wordpress plugins refresh without page refresh?

Tags: wordpress

I'm setting up a personal dashboard using Wordpress featuring information such as Time Zones, RSS News Ticker, Stocks Charts, Server Status...

However a large number of Wordpress Plugins available have been designed to be only refreshed when the page is loaded, which is not optimal for my dashboard.

Is there a way to force all plugins to reload every x seconds without having to refresh the page manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the plugins were designed to make asynchronous updates, I'm inclined to say no. Now, you could get creative and try to load each area into its own iframe, and then refresh each iframe periodically, but I think that's a poor solution.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, Chris. I'll look into iframes or try to find another solution allowing me to create flexible dashboards.